# Google Drive SDK for Android NotePad sample

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

Does anyone manage to get Google Drive Notepad sample for Android to work? I followed the instructions as given in Google's developer page but I could not get the notification to start the Google Play Service dialog for authorization.

The app starts as expected and when the method

```
credential.getToken();
```

is called, a `UserRecoverableAuthException` exception is raised. I expect that an authorization dialog will be shown, but nothing happens. I bring down the list of notification from the status bar, tap on the notification created by this app, and again nothing happens.

When I tap on the "Recent Apps" button, I could see "Google Play services" in the list, but it has empty (blank and black) content. Tapping it does nothing, except I was brought back to my home screen.

Any idea on this?

I tried the other sample app, "Quick Start Drive" and this one worked as expected. An authorization dialog was presented as I expected.

Further information, target device is Nexus 7 running OS 4.2.2.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please use the quickstart project as a starter: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android Notepad sample is outdated -- will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with :

```
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
Account account = null;
for(Account a : accounts){
    if(a.name.equals(accountName)){
        account = a;
        break;
    }
}

if(account != null){
    String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    accountManager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, true, null, null);

    service = getDriveService(credential);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To authorize Google Drive API, you have to catch the UserRecoverableException and trigger the intent to have an authorization dialog.

```
  try{
         .... 

  } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
          Intent intent = e.getIntent();
         startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_FOLDER);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabriele Mariotti, your solution seems better but can't work in that case. Indeed, the class is not an activity and the startActivityForResult method can't be called.

Comment: Pls use comment to replay.
Anyway you can insert Intent in a Notification (I didn't try it).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't add comment. I tried to insert the intent in a notification (as described here : https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android) but it didn't work for me.